# Is it true if $g\circ f$ is injective then $g$ is injective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, function-and-relation-composition

I need to know if this statement is true or false:

> If $g\circ f$ is injective then $g$ is injective.

I couldn't try to prove this statement. I was thinking to show a counter-example: $$\begin{array}{lll} f\colon\{1\}\to\{2,3\},&f(1)=1&\\g\colon\{2,3\}\to\{1\},&g(2)=1,&g(3)=1
\end{array}$$ But then I can't seem to show that $g\circ f$ is injective.

I would really appreciate any help on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That counterexample would work if $f$ were well defined.

Comment: The correct statement is that if $g \circ f$ is injective then $\left . g \right |_{f(A)}$ is injective.

Comment: Are you a student of mine?

Comment: Yes, I'm a student of yours;)

Comment: It only took four years, but finally I spot a student of mine asking here about homework! And you'd think it would happen sooner with my penchant for sophisticated questions. Congrats, you're the first person I notice asking here for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume that you mean $f(1)=2$, because $f(1)=1$ is not possible since $f\colon\{1\}\rightarrow\{2,3\}$).

Note that $g\circ f$ has domain $\{1\}$. Since the domain has only one element, $g\circ f$ is necessarily injective. Indeed, there does not exist $x,y$, different elements such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Thus the statement

> If $g\circ f$ is injective then $g$ is injective.

is false.

Comment: Alright so I need to prove that?

Comment: There is nothing to add to the proof! What I wrote is a proof of the fact that $g\circ f$ is injective. Since $g$ is not injective, it follows that the statement you had to discuss is false.

Comment: As domain is singleton then map has to be injective.From definition of mapping.Nothing to add in the srgument given by @rosebud

Comment: Ok I understand now